# Remove unwanted string from the input field in angular

Tags: angularjs, input-mask

I am trying to remove unwanted string which " _ " in my case . My input field is of IP mask address. I have used this

```
maskedInputs = {
    init: function() {
$("#mask_ip").inputmask({ 
    mask: "i[i[i]].i[i[i]].i[i[i]].i[i[i]]",
        definitions: {
            'i': {
                validator: function (chrs, buffer, pos, strict, opts) {
                if (pos - 1 > -1 && buffer[pos - 1] != ".") {
                chrs = buffer[pos - 1] + chrs;
                if (pos - 2 > -1 && buffer[pos - 2] != ".") {
                    chrs = buffer[pos - 2] + chrs;
                } else chrs = "0" + chrs;
            } else chrs = "00" + chrs;
            return new RegExp("25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]").test(chrs);
            },
            cardinality: 1
            }
        }
});
};
};
```

So my input field always have "_" (underscore) when passing the data.
Example:- if I leave last digits it will pass underscore. **192.168.0.0__** .

Is there any function or any method to eliminate character (here underscore) from passing with values ?

I tried using regex ,but the entire input is getting null.

**EDIT:-**

[image: IP mask view by default.]

Comment: replace `_` with the empty string. `str.replace(/_/g, "");`

Comment: @KaustubhKhare you mean to say by using regex ?

Comment: I have given you the `replace` function. Use this function to replace your input data.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare I am worried this is converting all the data to empty string " ". I am adding edit how my view look like.